# Is there a pdf viewer capable of opening multiple documents in the same window?

Tags: pdf, evince

I would like to open all chapters of my PDF ebooks in the same window but neither evince nor okular seems to be capable of doing that (at least not out-of-the-box).

Is there a way to work this out?

Comment: What about creating a single PDF with all chapters? `pdftk *.pdf cat output allchapters.pdf` Or open one instance per PDF and use your window manager, instead of the PDF reader, to manage the windows.

Comment: I second what Marco said. Most PDF viewers don't behave like web browsers.

Comment: Why is Okular not capable of using tabs? Just activate the according 'Open new files in tabs' in the settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [zathura](http://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) with [tabbed](http://tools.suckless.org/tabbed) might help here:

Tabbed provides a *"simple generic tabbed fronted to [xembed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XEmbed) aware applications"* and zathura is a simple PDF viewer that is XEmbed-aware.

A much more heavyweight approach would be letting a browser provide the tabbing while having the chapters displayed using plugins, e.g. using [mozplugger](http://mozplugger.mozdev.org/) (even [with evince](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/get-embedded-pdf-files-in-firefox-36-4.html)) or using [PDF.js](https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/pdfjs/) (both working with Firefox).

Regarding the all-mighty [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/), there's [a wishlist item](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=155515) and [a workaround using konqueror](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=95&t=40137#p58435) (like the heavyweight option above).

However, were you to use a window manager that supports tabbed layouts, e.g. [i3](http://i3wm.org/), [notion](http://notion.sourceforge.net/) or [XMonad](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-Tabbed.html) (there might be more!), any lightweight PDF-viewer (xembed'able or not) could work just fine.  You'd just open several windows in a tabbed window manager layout (details vary with the actual WM) -- *like [@Marco](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/12779/marco) suggested in his comment.*

Comment: To start zathura embedded into tabbed use `tabbed -c zathura -e`.

Answer (score 11):

[qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview) is a lightweight tabbed document viewer that should suit your needs.

It's in the default Ubuntu and Debian repos. More recent versions can be found in the following PPAs:

- [release versions](https://launchpad.net/~b-eltzner/+archive/qpdfview)
- [daily builds](https://code.launchpad.net/~adamreichold/+archive/qpdfview-dailydeb)
- [experimental builds for Ubuntu 12.04 with backported poppler](https://launchpad.net/~b-eltzner/+archive/qpdfview-exp)

Comment: qpdfview is nice light weight and great for the job

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend just setting PDFs to open in Firefox (or Chrome) at this point.

In GNOME Nautilus, this can be done using Properties -> Open With.
[image]

Unfortunately, the GNOME Evince document viewer maintainers have [made it clear](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/182#note_383805) they aren't going to add tabbed viewing support.

Comment: This is great but browser based readers often lack such features as highlighting which is why I love Edge. If we could get Edge for Linux, I would definitely use that. Chrome is not so great either.

Answer (score 2):

For my Okular is the best. Only you have to config:

[image: settings Okular]

Then you need to mark:

"Open new files in tabs"

[image: enable multitabs]