# How to do to make Evince open multiple pdf document in tabs and not separately?

Tags: pdf, evince

I would like to make Evince open multiple PDF documents in tabs instead of opening them separately; how can I accomplish that?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55485/is-there-a-pdf-viewer-capable-of-opening-multiple-documents-in-the-same-window. It's not possible with Evince, as far as I know. And I found nothing on the net to contradict that.

Comment: Does `evince` even have tabs?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible in Evince; unfortunately, the evince maintainers have [decided not to add tab support](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/182#note_383805).

You can just set PDFs to open in Firefox or Chromium